# HQL outer join on multiple columns

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I have one-to-many mapping in hibernate between a `Parent and a Child`. In the data base, `Child table` is having a `parentId` and few other details.
How can I outer join them in criteria or HQL on multiple columns.

ie, on `parentId` and `genderInd` etc.

Givern below a snipet of my code,

In the `Parent` class,

```
private parentId;

private Set<Child> childSet;
```

In the `Child` class,

```
private Long childId;

private Parent parent;

private String name;

private String genderInd;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `with` operator in the HQL.

`select p from Parent p left join p.childSet as cs with cs.genderInd = 'your_code'`

As told in the [HQL Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins),

> You may supply extra join conditions using the HQL with keyword.

```
from Cat as cat
    left join cat.kittens as kitten
        with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

Comment: I'm getting `with clause can only reference columns in the driving table` but I don't have the column I need in the `with` clause in the driving table. Is there anything I can do about that, please?

Comment: I have the same problem as @DawidFerenczyRogožan. Any help here ?